# Prestashop - How to add models to a manufacturer

Tags: prestashop

Im making a web with prestashop about motorcycles. I need let the client search in a select field the trademark of the moto (honda, yamaha) and in other one the specific type of the moto (Ex: Yamaha 445).

How can I do it? ive tried adding the product in a manufacturer but I dont know how to specify a type in them.

Important:

- I can't do it with categories/subcategories.
- I need that a product can be accessible from differents types of motorcycles.

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Because in the categories and subcategories I have the parts of the motocycle with the trademarks in them

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **Layered navigation block** module to achieve what you looking for.
It has 3 steps where you can 
1. specify where the layered filter will appear 
2. Select Product manufacturer
3. Name your template and save it.

This will automatically generate your filtered navigation and group your products as per the manufacturer